# Delete line if content is present on the next line too

Tags: text-processing

I have sample:

```
This is a test
localhost% This is a test
```

The first `This is a test` will re-appear in an txt file of next line that will has some chars `localhost%` before it. I'd like to remove the first `This is a test` if the next line contain something like `<arbitrary characters>% This is a test`

So I'd like to check two lines and if the previous line `This is a test` matched in next line `localhost% This is a test` (note about `%`), then delete the previous one.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: A little bit confused of myself, other tools would also works for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
sed '$!N;/^\(.*\)\n.*% \1$/!P;D'
```

That is have `sed` work on a rolling 2-line pattern space by using `N` with `D` and remove the first line (skip it by not (`!`) `P`rinting it) if it's found (`\(...\)` captured in `\1`) at the end (`$`) of the second line after `"% "`.

That should also work for things like:

> ```
> This is a test
> foo% This is a test
> bar% foo% This is a test
> ```

(removes the first 2 lines).

Comment: Yeah, can you do `sed`?, and `This is a test` is content of line that need to be deleted after check with next line that contains that content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below command

```
sed -i "/This is a test/s/^This is a test$//g" test && sed -i '/^$/d' test
```

Input file

cat test

```
This is a test
localhost% This is a test
```

After execution of above command

output file

cat test

```
localhost% This is a test
```

Comment: I think I should make more clear, `This is a test` is just one of the case, I'll update the #1.